# Does “Expired” certificate gets removed from the Apple's Developer Portal automatically?

Tags: ios, itunes, app-store-connect, developer-program, apple-store

Does "Expired" certificate gets removed from the Apple's Developer Portal automatically? I had a certificate for Development and Distribution on Apple's Developer Portal, but it expired, and now I can not see it on Developer Portal.

Does it get removed itself or somebody removed it (No one from my team mates deleted it) or did Xcode removed it, as we can now automatically handle Provisioning Profiles from Xcode?

Can we get a history of our Certificates on Developer Portal?

Answer (score 1):

My experience is no - Apple will not mess with your certificates and profiles and you will need to manage them once they are expired.

Think of the hassle of having a cert expire but not seeing it in your list so you know to take action to renew and replace it.

I'm gun shy to let Xcode "fix anything" automatically since then I'm at a disadvantage to remedy things when I need to manually make a change.